# How can I print the empty spaces with " | | " until the line ends

Tags: c++, formatting, output

I am working with vectors and I wanna know how I can print the empty spaces in between until the line ends.

```c++
void print_vector(const std::vector < int > & v, int print_cols, int col_width) {
  //dash
  cout << string(print_cols * (col_width + 2) + 1, '-');
  cout << endl;
  //printing the vector in formated output
  cout << "|";
  for (size_t x = 0; x < v.size(); x++) {

    cout << right << setw(col_width) << v[x] << " |";
    //prints new line if it reaches limit of numbers per line
    if ((x + 1) % print_cols == 0) cout << endl << "|";

  }

  //dash
  cout << endl << string(print_cols * (col_width + 2) + 1, '-');
  cout << endl;
}
```

this is my current output: [my output so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ5Ju.png) and sorry I can't embed images yet it wont let me.
But this is the output that I want [output needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaoy6.png)

Comment: Fyi, You don't have to embed images when your output is also text. Just copy it into a 'code' block as text. SO will do the rest.

Comment: You need another loop after the one you have printing empty blocks from `v.size()` to `print_cols`.

Comment: Okay thank you I will do that next time

Comment: Before posting their first question on stackoverflow.com, everyone should take the [tour], read the [help], understand all the requirements for a [mre] and [ask] questions here. Not doing any of this results in a poor quality question almost every time. It then gets downvoted, closed, and then deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void print_vector(const std::vector < int > & v, int print_cols, int col_width) {
  //dash
  cout << string(print_cols * (col_width + 2) + 1, '-');
  cout << endl;
  //printing the vector in formated output
  cout << "|";
  size_t x = 0;
  for (x = 0; x < v.size(); x++) {

    cout << right << setw(col_width) << v[x] << " |";
    //prints new line if it reaches limit of numbers per line
    if (x < v.size() - 1) {
      if ((x + 1) % print_cols == 0) {
         cout << endl << "|";
      }
    }

  }
  size_t remain = print_cols - (x % print_cols);
  for (size_t i = 0; (remain != print_cols) && i < remain; ++i) {
    cout << right << setw(col_width) << " " << " |";
  }
  //dash
  cout << endl << string(print_cols * (col_width + 2) + 1, '-');
  cout << endl;
}
```

Sample outputs:

```
-------------------------------------------------
|         1 |         2 |         3 |         4 |
|         5 |         6 |         7 |         8 |
|         9 |           |           |           |
-------------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------
|         1 |         2 |         3 |
|         4 |         5 |         6 |
|         7 |         8 |         9 |
-------------------------------------
```

Comment: Upvoted. I noticed my loop wasn't behaving correctly when the last element of the vector sat at the last column, and this code does. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra loop after the one you have and before the bottom row of dashes:

- The loop would print a given number of blank columns.
- The number of blank columns can be computed as `print_cols - v.size() % print_cols`.
- The loop should not be executed if the number of blank columns is equal to the total number of columns. That would print a full row of empty columns. That case happens when the vector you want to print has a number of elements that is an exact multiple of the number of columns.
- Every iteration of the loop should print `col_width + 1` blanks and a `'|'` (or if you prefer it, to make it more consistent with your other code, `col_width` blanks plus a `" |"`).

Yet you should fix another issue with your code:

- The check for reaching the end of the row (enabling the print of a new line and a `'|'`) should be instead a check for starting a row.

   
  If you do it at the end, for the case when the last element of the vector goes in the last column, you will unnecessarily add a new row.

   
  Doing it at the beginning, since you know you have at least one more number to show, you can print `"\n|"` and then the number.

   
  The check `x % print_cols == 0` will tell you if `x` is the index of the first element of a row.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/hWr4f7czx)

```cpp
#include <iomanip>  // setw
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <numeric>  // iota
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void print_vector(const std::vector<int>& v, int print_cols, int col_width) {
    // dash
    std::cout << std::string(print_cols * (col_width + 2) + 1, '-');

    // printing the vector in formated output
    for (size_t x = 0; x < v.size(); x++) {
        // prints new line if it is the first element of the line
        if (x % print_cols == 0) {
            std::cout << "\n|";
        }
        std::cout << std::right << std::setw(col_width) << v[x] << " |";
    }
    // prints last empty columns
    if (int number_of_blank_columns = print_cols - v.size() % print_cols;
        number_of_blank_columns != print_cols) {

        for (int x = 0; x < number_of_blank_columns; x++) {
            std::cout << std::string(col_width + 1, ' ') << "|";
        }
    }

    // dash
    std::cout << "\n" << std::string(print_cols * (col_width + 2) + 1, '-') << "\n";
}

int main() {
    {
        std::vector<int> v(8);
        std::iota(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 100);
        print_vector(v, 5, 4);
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    {
        std::vector<int> v(10);
        std::iota(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 100);
        print_vector(v, 5, 4);
    }
}

// Outputs:
//
//   -------------------------------
//   | 100 | 101 | 102 | 103 | 104 |
//   | 105 | 106 | 107 |     |     |
//   -------------------------------
//
//   -------------------------------
//   | 100 | 101 | 102 | 103 | 104 |
//   | 105 | 106 | 107 | 108 | 109 |
//   -------------------------------
```

Comment: Your like a lifesaver thank you

Comment: I'm glad if it helped!